# ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx broken in Dynamics 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to implement a custom web resource using jquery/ajax and odata. I ran into trouble and eventually found that when I call:

```
var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
```

The code throws exceptions.

However, when I change serverUrl to the literal url, it works. I then found forum posts that said I should verify my .aspx page manually by going to `https://[org url]//WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` to verify that it is working. When I did that I received a warning page:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'https://[org url]//WebResources/Clien...


document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+'\x26\x2347\x3b_common\x26\x2347\x3bglobal.ashx\x26\x2363\x3bver\x2...
```

What the heck does that mean?

Comment: Can you post up the code for the web resource? It is likely a formatting issue.

Comment: `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` is a script you should include your web resource to be able to access the context for your line thats trying to get the server url. `var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();`  it is likely that this script isnt correctly referenced causing the `serverUrl` variable to not be set and causing everything else to break.

Comment: I referenced it in my root htm file as:  <script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx">

Comment: Since my htm file was in a non-root 'folder', ie: I set the unique name as MyFolder/MyPage.htm I had to play around with the src attribute. I found that all of my scripts needed to be referenced relative to the htm itself. So logically referencing the aspx page as: ../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx seemed to work.

Comment: So it's working now? This is probably a bit late but [this article explains a bit about the referencing](http://dynamicscrm2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/crm-2011-web-resource-part-2-how-to-use-clientglobalcontext-js-aspx/)

Comment: On one of the CRM servers I have worked with, it was the issue because servername, servername.fully.qualifier.domain.name, and i.p.a.d.d.r.e.s.s are all different locations, also the PORT played a part, if it not set to 80, you have to consider that, I ended up partly hardcoding (grab servername from window.location) the thing. Best Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell outside of context (pun not intended) of your code, but why aren't you doing this?

```
var serverUrl =  Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
```

(Presumably, because you have defined your own context var?)

Also, this method is deprecated as of Rollup 12, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7d0b052-abca-4f81-9b86-0b9dc5e62a66. You can now use getClientUrl instead.

Answer (score 0):

I now it is late but hope this will be useful for other people who will face this problem.
Until nowadays even with R15 there are two available **ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx**

1. **https://[org url]/WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx**  (the bad one)
2. **https://[org url]/[organization name]/[publication id]/WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx** (The good one)

I don't know why exist 1. but it causes many issues like:

- It could not be published or hold information (Your case @Steve).
- In a deployment with multiple organizations, seems it saves info only for the last organization    deployed causing that methods under **Xrm.Page.context.** will return info from a fixed organization. Actually each method that underground uses these constants included in **ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx**: USER_GUID, ORG_LANGUAGE_CODE, ORG_UNIQUE_NAME, SERVER_URL, USER_LANGUAGE_CODE, USER_ROLES, CRM2007_WEBSERVICE_NS, CRM2007_CORETYPES_NS, AUTHENTICATION_TYPE, CURRENT_THEME_TYPE, CURRENT_WEB_THEME, IS_OUTLOOK_CLIENT, IS_OUTLOOK_LAPTOP_CLIENT, IS_OUTLOOK_14_CLIENT, IS_ONLINE, LOCID_UNRECOGNIZE_DOTC, EDIT_PRELOAD, WEB_SERVER_HOST, WEB_SERVER_PORT, IS_PATHBASEDURLS, LOCID_UNRECOGNIZE_DOTC, EDIT_PRELOAD,  WEB_RESOURCE_ORG_VERSION_NUMBER, YAMMER_IS_INSTALLED,  YAMMER_IS_CONFIGURED_FOR_ORG, YAMMER_APP_ID, YAMMER_NETWORK_NAME, YAMMER_GROUP_ID, YAMMER_TOKEN_EXPIRED, YAMMER_IS_CONFIGURED_FOR_USER, YAMMER_HAS_CONFIGURE_PRIVILEGE, YAMMER_POST_METHOD. For instance method **Xrm.Page.context.getUserId()** is implemented as `return window.USER_GUID;`

To be sure that your URL is the correct just follow [the link](http://dynamicscrm2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/crm-2011-web-resource-part-2-how-to-use-clientglobalcontext-js-aspx/) posted by @Chris